# Let $f\in L^{1}([0,1],m)$. Assume that for every interval $I\subset[0,1]$ with $m(I) = c$, we have $\int_{I} f dm =0$. Do we have $f=0$ a.e.?

Tags: real-analysis

Fix a constant $0<c<1$. Let $f\in L^{1}([0,1],m)$. Assume that for every interval
$I\subset[0,1]$ with $m(I) = c$, we have $\int_{I} f dm =0$. Do we have $f=0$ almost everywhere?

It's related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1532527/if-int-a-f-dm-0-for-all-a-having-some-fixed-measure-c-then-f-0-al/1533001#1533001). There it is shown that if $\int_{A} f dm =0$ for every measurable $A\subset[0,1]$ with with $m(A) = c$, then $f=0$ almost everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Take for example $f(x)=\sin\left(\frac{2\pi }{c}x\right)$.